# Pandas Parsing String with Multiple Elements and Multiple Delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have an Excel file with 27 columns. I have one column called "Users" which has multiple elements. Each element is separated on a new line in Excel in the same cell, and each sub-element is separated by a semicolon (;) between surrounding parentheses (()). However, parentheses may exist within the sub-elements as well. An image of how the table is displayed in Excel is below using sample data.

[image: Data Table]

Here is how it imports into Python as a DataFrame using Pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['WB-01','ZD-DD','DE-02','WZ-D8','HJ-78'],
                   'Type': ['First','Second','First','Second','Third'],
                   'Status': ['Completed','Started','Started','Final','Pending'],
                   'User': ['Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)','Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)','Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)',  'Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)', 'Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nAdmin Assistant (WRIST PAD; wristpad@domain.com; 999 999 9999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)']
                   })
```

**Logic**

Now, I want to apply the following logic and create a new column called ownership.
If `Status = 'Completed'` Then `Ownership = 'Completed'`
If `Status = 'Started'` Then `Ownership =` the name of every `Admin`.
If `Status = 'Final'` Then `Ownership =` the name of every `Supervisor`.
If `Status = 'Pending'` Then `Ownership =` the  name of every `Admin Assistant`.

Possible user roles are `'Admin', 'Admin Assistant', 'Supervisor',` and  `'Alternative Supervisor'`. The first sub-element within the parentheses is the name of the person in that role. The second sub-element is the e-mail address. The third sub-element is a non-standardized telephone number. It could have dashes, it could have parentheses, it could have spaces, or all together. The delimiter in the sub-elements is the semicolon `;`. I BELIEVE the delimiter between the elements is `\n` in Python, as that is how it displays when I import that DataFrame (using the script above).

```
Status     User Role
Started    Admin
Pending    Admin Assistant
Final      Supervisor
Completed  Completed
```

**Desired Results**
[image: Desired Results]

Python script for desired results.

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['WB-01','ZD-DD','DE-02','WZ-D8','HJ-78'],
                           'Type': ['First','Second','First','Second','Third'],
                           'Status': ['Completed','Started','Started','Final','Pending'],
                           'User': ['Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)','Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)','Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)',  'Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)', 'Admin (PAPER CLIP; paper.clip@domain.com; 999999999)\nAdmin (THUMB TACK; thumbtack@domain.com; 999-999-999)\nAdmin Assistant (MOUSE PAD; mousepad@domain.com; (999) 999999)\nAdmin Assistant (WRIST PAD; wristpad@domain.com; 999 999 9999)\nSupervisor (WHITE BOARD; whiteboard@domain.com; 999-999999)\nAlternative Supervisor (CHALK BOARD; chalkboard@domain.com; (999) 999-999)'],
                           'Ownership': ['Completed','PAPER CLIP','PAPER CLIP, THUMB TACK','WHITE BOARD','MOUSE PAD, WRIST PAD']
                           })
```

I tried to use the `.split` function, but I can't figure out how to do a split with multiple elements and multiple delimiters, especially when multiple parentheses may exist. Then, I didn't know how to extract only certain elements from that field since there could be potentially multiple instances based on the condition of another field.

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First task is to extract all roles' names, the other task is easy:

```
roles = (df['User'].str.split('\n', expand=True)
     .stack()
     .str.extract('^([\w\s]*)\s+\(([\w\s]*)[;|\)]')
     .reset_index()
     .groupby(['level_0', 0])[1]
     .agg(', '.join)
     .unstack(level=0)
)

# assign Completed ownership
roles['Completed'] = 'Completed'

ownership_mask = {
    'Started' : 'Admin',
    'Pending' : 'Admin Assistant',
    'Final'   : 'Supervisor',
    'Completed': 'Completed'
}

df['ownership'] = roles.lookup(df.index, df['Status'].map(ownership_mask))
```

Output (`df['Status']`):

```
0                 Completed
1                PAPER CLIP
2    PAPER CLIP, THUMB TACK
3               WHITE BOARD
4      MOUSE PAD, WRIST PAD
Name: ownership, dtype: object
```

**Note** Instead of `df['Status'].map`, we can use `np.select`:

```
# no need to do `roles['Completed'] = 'Completed':
df['Ownership'] = np.select([df['Status'].eq('Started'),
                             df['Status'].eq('Pending'),
                             df['Status'].eq('Final')],
                            [roles['Admin'], roles['Admin Assistant'], roles['Supervisor'] ],
                            'Completed'
                           )
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution, but I get an `Invalid Syntax` error pointing to the last parenthesis. I do the `roles = ...`, and then I do the last black of `df['Ownership']  = np.select...`.  It works for me using the `df['Status'].map`. I'm not quite sure how it all works though, I'm still deciphering it. I greatly appreciate it! If you have a moment, would you mind explaining your solution?

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey there's a missing `]` . Updated.

Comment: Got it! Wow, that was a very quick solution. I really appreciate it! Now to really try to understand what you did.